# JavaScript getElementById not Working

Tags: javascript

I need help with this code if someone is willing to help. I cannot get the 2 getElementById functions to work and I am a beginner so I am sure it is something simple but I have not been able to fix it. I need to click on the text to change the font. Any help in the right direction will be greatly apprecited. Please check the code below.

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
        <title>Solution Page 486 Exercise 12.7</title>
   <style type = "text/css">
           .option { color: darkblue }
           .graybg { background-color: #aaaaaa }
           .whitebg { background-color: #ffffff }
           .sans { font-family: sans-serif }
           .serif { font-family: serif }
        </style>
<script type = "text/javascript">
           function bodyClass(color)
          {
              document.body.className = color;
          }

        </script>
     </head>

     <body>
        <div id = "main">Click on Options Listed Below to see how they modify this page.<br ><br >
          <div>Options:
          <div onclick = "bodyClass('graybg');"
                class = "option">Gray background</div>
              <div onclick = "bodyClass('whitebg');"
                class = "option">White background</div>
             <div onclick = "document.getElementById("  class
                 = "option" classname ="sans" ? main?).>Sans-serif text</div>
             <div onclick = "document.getElementById("  class
                 = "option" classname ="serif" ? main?).>Serif text</div></div></div>
     </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Your markup is all messed up. `<div onclick = "document.getElementById('YOUR_ID_HERE')" ....>` is how it should be

Comment: getElementById is exactly that, it will get an element by it's ID, for example document.getElementById("main") would then get the div with the id="main" like you have above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not write JavaScript in a string assigned to an 'onclick' property. Write it in a function in a  tag and assign the function,here is the code:

```
<body>
...
<div id='an_id'> <!-- doesn't have to be a div, any element is OK -->
...
<script type='text/JavaScript'>
    var some_elem = document.getElementById( 'an_id' );
        some_elem.onclick = my_func; // no parens, no quotes!

    function my_func() {
        // your code goes here
        // in here, 'this' refers to the element that got the click
    }
</script>

</body>
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of `getElementById` is:

```
document.getElementById('the_id_of_an_element')
```

You have:

```
document.getElementById(
```

You need to give it an argument and include the closing `)`.  You then probably want to do something with the return value.

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementById itself says it fetch element by Id but not by class or any other attributes, this should work `document.getElementById('main')`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't understand how getElementById works:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function onButtonClick() {{
      document.getElementById( "main" ).innerHTML = "html of div main has changed!";
    };
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="main">This is the initial text</div>
  <button onclick="onButtonClick();">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

save the above code as "test.html", load it in a browser, click button, see effect.

`<div id="main">` <= id="main" means that you give an identifier to the "div" element, when you call "document.getElementById", you need to pass the value of "id", in this case "main".